# Can I do a color swap like Among Us in OpenFL?

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

Can I do a color swap like Among Us in a game I am creating with Haxe, OpenFL and HaxeFlixel?

I found a sprite from Among Us that looks like this

[Among Us Idle Sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNDaF.png)

Can I use shaders or code to make this color like the following?
(When I used threshold on the Bitmap, other colors were also changed)

[Among Us Black Idle Sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUwhb.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact use a shader (you can find a polite introduction [here](https://community.openfl.org/t/drawquads-and-atlases/10928/2?u=13rice)<sup>([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20230223113447/https://community.openfl.org/t/drawquads-and-atlases/10928/2))</sup>) - as you can see from the sprite, the idea is essentially

```c
out.a = in.a;
out.rgb = colorUniform1.rgb * in.r + colorUniform2.rgb * in.g + colorUniform3.rgb * in.b;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shader like the HueSaturationShader that allows you to shift the colors to a different part of the spectrum. You can find an implementation for openfl [here](https://github.com/loudoweb/openfl-shaders/blob/master/openfl/shaders/HueSaturationShader.hx). You could use it that way:

```
sprite.shader = new openfl.shaders.HueSaturationShader(hue,saturation);
```

You can even control the color on enter frame:

```
//declaration
var hueShader = new HueSaturationShader();
sprite.shader = hueShader ;
//on enter frame
hueShader.data.hue.value = [0.5];
```